# Database to Excel SSIS Dynamic creation

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ssis, ssms

Explanation: I have an excel file that will be placed into a folder every day. There is normally about 5-7 worksheets inside that excel file. Each worksheet has the same column schema. I have an ssis package that extracts the data into a table and runs a procedure to several more columns of derived data to the original in the table. After the data has been added to the table i need to export it out into the excel file (Which will be the final complete report).

The ssis package has to For-Each Loops. One to loop through the excel files. and one inside that to loop through the sheets in the file. My initial idea was that i could just load straight from the database table back into the original excel file and overwrite all the data existing in there. Only problem is there is more columns in the table than can be mapped to the excel spreadsheet (because it originally only contains the 7 before the procedure is run). I have looked into dynamic excel creation but this seems over complicated for something that should be able to just be overwritten.

The process will work one sheet at a time, extract the data, build the extra data in the table, export the entire table back to the excel file. Rinse and repeat for the next several sheets in the excel file.

What would be the best approach for Reloading the data from the table back into the excel spreadsheet WITH the new columns also. Is dynamic excel sheet creation best for this? Or is there a better way to remap new columns to the existing spreadsheet and just add in the new data?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I would suggest creating a new spreadsheet for your result. If you already have the code to read from an spreadsheet, it would be easier to create the spreadsheet as well. Btw, how are you reading from the spreadsheet ? It would be good to post some code. In most cases, a CSV file (which is just the text data separated by commas) is as good as an spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you make an excel file with the columns and use it as a template? Save it into a folder and make a file copy task to copy it. Then populate the copy.

Comment: @Subbu I am reading from the excel sheet using the ssis excel source component in a data flow task. The format of the original file is .xlsx.

Comment: @JacobH The problem with this approach is that depending on the day, the excel file could have 5 sheets, or could have 7, So if i was to keep a template copy i wouldn't always have the right amount of sheets. or have to many. I also need to have the sheets named exactly like they were in the original file as they are separated by date. so sheet1 would be named "Orders 08-10", sheet2 would be "Orders 08-11".

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need a script task. I don't think there is a way to rename sheets in a workbook via SSIS. If there is I hope someone posts it because I have a similar issue that I need to solve!